# Zend Registry in ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hello i am trying to override array value

So i have something like this.

```
Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
```

$**config** is array

```
 $config = ['timeZone' => 'GMT'];
```

is it possible to override just single value in already set array not whole array.

for Example something like this

```
 Zend_Registry::set('config::timeZone', 'NewOne');
```

Zend_Reistry has inheritance from ArrayObject, so if that is possible in SPL ArrayObject, so if that is possible in SPL, it's possible here, but i can't find reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not via the `set` method. The `set` method simply calls `ArrayObject::offsetSet`, and there is no magic there. You're on the right track though, since `Zend_Registry` extends `ArrayObject`, we can access the contents using standard array syntax, so you can treat an instance of `ZendRegistry` like an array that has your config array at the index "config".

```
<?php
// Create our config array
$config = [
    'country' => 'US',
    'lang' => 'EN',
    'timeZone' => 'EST'
];

// Set it in the registry
Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);

// Since registry extends ArrayObject, we can access the contents like an array
Zend_Registry::getInstance()['config']['timeZone'] = 'GMT';

// Get our config from the registry
$updatedConfig = Zend_Registry::get('config');

// Verify that the timeZone was updated
assert($updatedConfig['timeZone']=='GMT');
```